# C: switch case with hex value ignore the 0 in the front

Tags: c, android-ndk, switch-statement

I init a `uint32` variable by shifting two `uint8` variables.

```
uint32_t test = ((first_uint8 << 16) | second_uint8);
```

In my test, the value of `test` should be 0x00170001 (0x17<<16|0x01)

Then it runs into a `switch case`

```
switch(test) {
   case 0x00170001:
        //do sth
        break;
   default:
        //printf invalid
        break;
}
```

It should go to the first case, however, it always run into default.

Then I `printf("%x", test)`, the result is 0x170001, which is equal to 0x00170001.

At last I try to modify it like this:

```
switch(test) {
   case 0x170001:
        //do sth
        break;
   default:
        //printf invalid
        break;
}
```

Then it works well.

So I'm curious about the result.

1. for a uint32_t variable, why 0x170001 does not equal to 0x00170001?
2. if it is caused by I didn't memset `test` by 0, then `test` should also not be equal to 0x170001, it should be 0x11170001 or something with a garbage first byte.?
3. is it caused by the compiler ignores the `0` in the front of hex value? I'm using Android NDK to compile my c code.

Comment: String representation doesn't matter. The problem is elsewhere. Numbers are numbers and you can print them however you want, the computer still considers them numbers and not strings. Debugging line by line?

Comment: For such a simple `switch` with just one case and then a `default`, then why not use a `if-else`?

Comment: Your code says `uint32_t test = first_uint8 << 16 | second_uint8;` (I'd put brackets around the `(first_uint8 << 16)` personally) but your text says `(0x17<<8|0x01)`, an 8-bit shift instead of 16. I cannot really image a compiler bug, so are you sure you didn't alter other code along with changing `0x00170001` to `0x170001`? What happens if you change back now?

Comment: Can't be reproduced here: http://ideone.com/UR566Q So either your compiler has a bug (which I doubt) or the code posted isn't the code you are running.

Comment: @KenY-N sorry,my typo. should be << 16

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen cause there are many other cases. I just start dealing with the first one, so there is only one number in my test.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, a `switch` is adequate, for example, in case code maintainance shows that more values can fit in there, in the future.  As compilers today optimize code, **there's no difference** normally, in efficience, in using a two cases `switch` or an `if`/`else` statement.  Why do we tend to make critics to all programming styles other people show?

Comment: @lanyusea, did you learn at school that leading zeros are of no significance in front of an integer number?  Well, in C it's the same (even in hexadecimal)  So `0x1` is exactly the same number as `0x000000000001`.  If you want to format it to appear as in the second case, just use `"%08x"` as format specifier, instead of plain `"%x"`.

Comment: @LuisColorado Thanks Luis. Yes I know that. So I was very puzzled and shocked when I saw the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. for a uint32_t variable, why 0x170001 does not equal to 0x00170001?

It does. 0x170001, 0x0170001 and 0x00170001 are all equal.

> 2.if it is caused by I didn't memset test by 0, then test should also not be equal to 0x170001, it should be 0x11170001 or something with a garbage first byte.?

It is **not** caused by a missing `memset`. Any assignment `test = X` will set **all** bits in `test`.

> 3.is it caused by the compiler ignores the 0 in the front of hex value? I'm using Android NDK to compile my c code.

That could explain it but **I doubt it**. I think it is more likely that your being tricked by something else. Perhaps you are not actually running the code, you think. If it really turns out that it makes a difference whether you write `0x170001` or `0x00170001`, you should report it as a compiler bug - but be really sure before doing that.

See here for a working example compiled with `gcc` : http://ideone.com/UR566Q

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just checkout the commit before I change 0x0017 to 0x17 and connect to the same hardware and recompile the code. This bug blocks me the whole morning just disappeared. I have no idea and felt a little angry.... It seems you are right, I meet an uncertain behavior of compiler I guess. Anyway, thanks for your answer.